# communicating between winForms C# (Log-in process)

Tags: c#, winforms

Introduction of problem:

I have two forms `Home.cs` and `Login.cs`. I have `ToolStripMenuItems` in `Home.cs`, Admin will log-in from the `Login.cs` form. On `form_load (Home.cs)` event I had made two menu items disabled.

```
addToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

After successful login I want to enable those menu items in `Home.cs`. But is not able to figure out how to do that in C#. I thought I can do something like this:

```
private Home hm = null;
```

and then in authentication event I can do....

```
hm.addToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
```

Problem:

But this is not working, and this is not the right way to handle this situation. Plz help......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply call the Login.cs from the Load event of the Home.cs form/class , just like that:

```
 public void Home_Load(...params...)
 { 
    Login log = new Login();
      if(log.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
         {
            // enable the menu here
         }
       else 
        {
          // let the menu disabled or exit the application here
        }
 }
```